# Migrations are pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: Ayuda por favor!! Primero pongo rails server en la consola y cuando pongo en el navegador localHost:3000 me aparece este mensaje, como lo puedo resolver?]

Primero pongo rails server en la consola y cuando pongo en el navegador localHost:3000 me aparece este mensaje, como lo puedo resolver?

Comment: Pues el problema es claro, no has hecho las migraciones, y ahi mismo te dan la respuesta: `bin/rails migrate RAILS_ENV=development`.

Comment: Hola, gracias y si eso lo entiendo pero como las hago? se escriben tal cual en la consola?

Comment: Supongo que si. La verdad no uso `rails`, pero la solución está muy clara y con unas chicas letrotas coloradas.

Comment: pues si pero lo pongo tal cual y aun asi no funciona :(

Comment: ¿Pero te sale algún al correr las migraciones? podrías probar a borrar la bd y correr las migraciones desde cero a ver como te va, o cargar el esquema de la bd ya creado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te han indicado en los comentarios, no has ejecutado las migraciones necesarias. Eso quiere decir que tienes archivos en db/migrate con una fecha superior a la que tienes en tu db/schema.rb
Para solucionar esto, tienes que ejecutar las migraciones. Simplemente ejecuta en la terminal:

```
rake db:migrate db:test:prepare
```

La primera parte, ejecutará todos los archivos de migración cuya fecha sea inferior a la que está en el schema.rb. Date cuenta de que la fecha es la que tiene el archivo. 
Así por ejemplo 20170220141221 Está especificando la fecha con AñoMesDiaHoraMinutoSegundo.

La segunda parte: db:test:prepare, copia el schema para la base de datos de test. Por lo tanto, al ejecutar los dos, preparas tanto la base de datos de desarrollo como la de test.

Answer (score 0):

En tu consola dentro de la carpeta de tu proyecto necesitas correr las migration si tienes **rails 5 o mayor** el comando es `rails db:migrate`

si tienes una version de **rails menor a la version 5** entonces el comando es

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:migrate` debería servir

Comment: muchas gracias, hice lo que escribiste y ya quedo solucionado

Comment: acepta la respuesta y puntuala plis! (flechita hacia arriba y visto bueno al lado de la respuesta)